# CUPS and OS X - client-error-not-authorized for Create-Job

Tags: printing, cups-lpd, lpd

Cups running on Ubuntu 15.10 server and so far so good.

When an OS X device tries to print through the ubuntu cups server, I get this error:

```
IPP client-error-not-authorized for Create-Job
```

On the OS X device in the print job I get the message:

```
Hold for Authorization
```

Made the standard tweaks to cupsd.conf and printers.conf (see below), but no joy.

Any cups experts have any advice?

Thanks

Luis

cupsd.conf:

```
#
# Configuration file for the CUPS scheduler.  See "man cupsd.conf" for a
# complete description of this file.
#

# Log general information in error_log - change "warn" to "debug"
# for troubleshooting...
LogLevel debug
PageLogFormat

# Deactivate CUPS' internal logrotating, as we provide a better one, especially
# LogLevel debug2 gets usable now
MaxLogSize 0

# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
#Listen localhost:631
Port 631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock

# Show shared printers on the local network.
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd
#BrowseAllow all
# Default authentication type, when authentication is required...
DefaultAuthType None

# Web interface setting...
WebInterface Yes

# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>

# Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>

# Set the default printer/job policies...
<Policy default>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Ren
ew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Canc
el-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Dev
ices>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release
-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-J
ob-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>

# Set the authenticated printer/job policies...
<Policy authenticated>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Ren
ew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Canc
el-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release
-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-J
ob-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
```

printers.conf:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v2.1.0
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<Printer SHARP_MX-2640N>
UUID urn:uuid:ce9f69de-ba08-3630-7365-088439080a0f
AuthInfoRequired none
Info SHARP MX-2640NPCL_PS
Location Local Printer
MakeModel Sharp MX-2640N PS, 1.1
DeviceURI lpd://192.168.25.52/lp
State Idle
StateTime 1449759918
ConfigTime 1449702658
Type 8401116
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
AllowUser all
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
Attribute marker-colors \#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,#000000,none,#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,#000000,#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,#000
000,none
Attribute marker-levels 35,50,-1,75,0,73,73,73,63,73,73,73,63,-1
Attribute marker-names Cyan Toner,Magenta Toner,Yellow Toner,Black Toner,Waste Toner,Cyan Photoconductive Drum,Magenta Pho
toconductive Drum,Yellow Photoconductive Drum,Black Photoconductive Drum,Cyan Developer,Magenta Developer,Yellow Developer
,Black Developer,Fusing Unit
Attribute marker-types toner,toner,toner,toner,waste-toner,opc,opc,opc,opc,developer,developer,developer,developer,fuser
Attribute marker-change-time 1449759918
</Printer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After MUCH searching found the problem.

In printers.conf changed

```
AllowUser all
```

to

```
AllowUser
```

and yes, that is all that I needed to change...weirdo!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed there was a continuous error 'Create-Job client-error-not-authorized: The printer or class is not shared!' in the CUPS errors logs when a print job was queued on the local PC printer queue. I removed the HP laserjet 6MP printer under CUPS admin again and installed it as ‘Share This Printer’ with the settings. This time I used the PCL 6 driver with its default options.  That fixed it. A print test job worked from the PC. Re installation of the IPP printer was not required on the PC.